# CollectionView cells not appearing correctly using mmPlayerView

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionview that contains a video, a caption, profile image and a few other labels in each cell. When I load the collection view the first cell loads perfectly. Everything is all showing in the correct position. The rest however is loaded incorrectly for example sometimes the video does not fit properly within the imageview so it looks like its been cut out or sometimes the caption doesn't show at all.

But when I scroll down more a cell might randomly show everything in the correct positions again. I am using a library MMPlayerView to load my videos into the cell. I have been trying to figure out why the first cell loads perfectly but then the rest doesn't?

I am trying to create a collectionview that just plays videos like Instagram. I've also build out the collectionview programmatically if someone needs to know.

viewController

```
lazy var mmPlayerLayer: MMPlayerLayer = {
    let l = MMPlayerLayer()
    l.cacheType = .memory(count: 5)
    l.coverFitType = .fitToPlayerView
    l.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    l.replace(cover: CoverA.instantiateFromNib())
    return l
}()

@IBOutlet weak var newsfeedCollectionView: UICollectionView!

var videoPosts = [videoPost]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    newsfeedCollectionView?.register(videoListCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)       
    newsfeedCollectionView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentOffset", options: [.new], context: nil)
    newsfeedCollectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 20, right:0)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
        self.updateByContentOffset()
        self.startLoading()
    }

    fetchAllPosts()
}

fileprivate func landscapeAction() {
    // just landscape when last result was finish
    if self.newsfeedCollectionView.isDragging || self.newsfeedCollectionView.isTracking || self.presentedViewController != nil {
        return
    }
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        let full = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FullScreenViewController") as! FullScreenViewController
        MMLandscapeWindow.shared.makeKey(root: full, playLayer: self.mmPlayerLayer, completed: {
            print("landscape completed")
        })
    }
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "contentOffset" {
        self.updateByContentOffset()
        NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self)
        self.perform(#selector(startLoading), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.3)

    } else {
        super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
    }
}

func fetchAllPosts() {

  //posts are loaded from firebase 
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return videoPosts.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! videoListCollectionViewCell       
    let postModelInfo = videoPosts[indexPath.item]
    cell.post = postModelInfo

    return cell
}

fileprivate func updateByContentOffset() {
    let p = CGPoint(x: newsfeedCollectionView.frame.width/2, y: newsfeedCollectionView.contentOffset.y + newsfeedCollectionView.frame.width/2)

    if let path = newsfeedCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: p),
        self.presentedViewController == nil {
        self.updateCell(at: path)
    }
}

fileprivate func updateCell(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = newsfeedCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? videoListCollectionViewCell {

        cell.delegate = self
        cell.videoDelegate = self

        // this thumb use when transition start and your video dosent start
        mmPlayerLayer.thumbImageView.image = cell.photoImageView.image

        // set video where to play
        if !MMLandscapeWindow.shared.isKeyWindow {
            mmPlayerLayer.playView = cell.photoImageView   
        }

        // set url prepare to load
        mmPlayerLayer.set(url: URL(string:(cell.post?.videoUrl)!), state: { (status) in
            switch status {
            case .failed(let err):
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "error", message: err.description, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            case .ready:
                print("Ready to Play")
            case .playing:
                print("Playing")
            case .pause:
                print("Pause")
            case .end:
                print("End")
            default: break
            }
        })

        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    }


}

@objc fileprivate func startLoading() {
    if self.presentedViewController != nil {
        return
    }
    // start loading video
    mmPlayerLayer.startLoading()
    self.landscapeAction()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let post = videoPosts[indexPath.item]

        let width = (view.frame.width)
        let imageWidth = post.imageWidth?.floatValue,
        imageHeight = post.imageHeight?.floatValue
        let oldHeight = CGFloat(imageWidth! / imageHeight!)
        let height = CGFloat(width / oldHeight + 138)

        let rect = NSString(string: post.postCaption!).boundingRect(with: CGSize(width:view.frame.width, height:1000), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin), attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)], context: nil)

        return CGSize(width:view.frame.width, height:rect.height + height)

}
```

CollectionViewCell

```
protocol mmPlayerDelegate{
     func startLoading(for cell: videoListCollectionViewCell)
}
class videoListCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var delegate: PostCellDelegate?
    var videoDelegate: videoDelegate?
    var mmPlayerDelegate: mmPlayerDelegate?

    var post: videoPost? {
        didSet {

            guard let postImageUrl = post?.imageUrl else { return }       
            self.photoImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: postImageUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "blurLogo"))
            self.userProfileImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: post?.profilePic), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "blurLogo"))          
           usernameLabel.text = post?.fullName
           captionLabel.text = post!.postCaption      
    }

     override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        post = nil
    }

    let userProfileImageView: CustomImageView = {
        var iv = CustomImageView()
        iv.image = UIImage(named:"blurLogo")
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iv.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        return iv
    }()   
    var photoImageView: CustomImageView = {
        var iv = CustomImageView()
        iv.image = UIImage(named:"blurLogo")
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iv.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return iv
    }()    
    let usernameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = ""
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        return label
    }()   
    let postDate: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = ""
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 10)
        label.textColor = UIColor.gray
        return label
    }()   
    let likeCount: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "0"
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        return label
    }()
    let optionsButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle("•••", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        return button
    }()
    lazy var likeButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        let stencil =  imageLiteral(resourceName: "like_unselected").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        button.setImage(stencil, for: .normal)
        button.tintColor = UIColor.white
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLike), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }() 
    lazy var commentButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        let stencil =  imageLiteral(resourceName: "comment").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        button.setImage(stencil, for: .normal)
        button.tintColor = UIColor.white
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleComment), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()    
    let captionLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        return label
    }()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(userProfileImageView)
        addSubview(usernameLabel)
        addSubview(optionsButton)
        addSubview(photoImageView)


        userProfileImageView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 8, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 40, height: 40)

        userProfileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 40 / 2

        usernameLabel.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: userProfileImageView.rightAnchor, bottom: photoImageView.topAnchor, right: optionsButton.leftAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

        photoImageView.anchor(top: userProfileImageView.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 16, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

        addSubview(postDate)
        postDate.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: photoImageView.topAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 8, width: 0, height: 0)

        optionsButton.anchor(top: photoImageView.bottomAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 15, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 44, height: 0)

        addSubview(fullScreen)
        fullScreen.anchor(top: nil, left: nil , bottom: photoImageView.bottomAnchor, right: photoImageView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 15, paddingRight: 15, width: 30, height: 30)

        addSubview(activityIndicatorView)
        activityIndicatorView.anchor(top: photoImageView.centerYAnchor, left: photoImageView.centerXAnchor , bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: -15, paddingLeft: -15, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

        setupActionButtons()

        addSubview(likeCountButton)
        likeCountButton.anchor(top: photoImageView.bottomAnchor, left: likeButton.rightAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 16, paddingLeft: -18, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

        addSubview(captionLabel)
        captionLabel.anchor(top: likeButton.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 6, paddingRight: 8, width: 0, height: 0)

        addSubview(viewCount)
        viewCount.anchor(top: captionLabel.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 6, paddingRight: 8, width: 0, height: 0)
    }

    fileprivate func setupActionButtons() {
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [likeButton, likeCount,commentButton, commentCount])
        stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally

        addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.anchor(top: photoImageView.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 190, height: 50)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things which might need changing in your code to achieve what you need:

1. Dont use `sizeForItemAt` to derive the height of custom cell.
2. Instead use `estimatedItemSize` in your `viewDidLoad`.
3. Compute the height for the cell depending on the content for the cell in `didSet` function for `post`.